# Axis edits in interactive mode ion() in matplotlib are ignored - scope problem?

Tags: python, axis, python-interactive

I would like to make a plot from a data array that grows in time. I found ion() to redraw my plot, adding new points. Now, adding a new point should erase an old one and to achieve that I had to add clf(). This again means I have to reset my axis edits every time I plot, but it ignores every modification that depends on the axis handle. I was wondering if this is a scope problem because of the function I call? I am new to python and would also appreciate feedback in case there is a more straightforward approach than the one chosen.

I tried to pass the axis handle through the different functions in hope this would change things, but without success.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
from time import time

x, y = [], []
counter = 0
plt.ion()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()      # ax1 is not used

def axis(ax):
    ax.set_label("Time [s]")
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(base=0.5))

def plot():
    plt.clf()
    ax = plt.gca()
    axis(ax)
    if len(y) < 3:
        plt.plot(x, y, c='r')
    else:
        plt.plot(x[-3:], y[-3:], c='r')
    plt.draw()
    return ax


for i in range(0,10):
    x.append(time())
    y.append(counter)
    print(i, '\n')
    ax = plot()
    counter +=1
    plt.pause(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing of ax not needed. Substituting plt.clf() with ax1.clear() solved the issue.